# C lang CGI form/string handle

Tags: c, cgi

Started playing with C and CGI forms.
Is this code ok? Can it be improved/optimized?

If I fill user with "user" and password with "pass" input in takelogin is `user=user&password=pass`

In the end I want to have `user = 'user'` and `pass = 'pass'`

This is the form

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s%c%c\n", "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
    printf("<title>Takelogin</title>\n");
    printf("<h3>Multiplication results</h3>\n");
    printf("%s\n", "<form action='/takelogin.cgi' method='post'>");
    printf("%s\n", "<div>Your input (80 chars max.):<BR>");
    printf("%s\n", "<input type='text' name='user' size='60' maxlength='80'><br>");
    printf("%s\n", "<input type='password' name='password' size='60' maxlength='80'><br>");
    printf("%s\n", "<input type='submit' value='Send'></div>");
    printf("%s\n", "</form>");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is takelogin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXINPUT 80

int main(void)
{
    char *lenstr;
    char *user;
    char *pass;
    char input[MAXINPUT];
    long len;
    char delim[2][2] = {"&", '='};

    printf("%s%c%c\n",
    "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
    printf("<TITLE>Response</TITLE>\n");

    lenstr = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
    if(lenstr == NULL)
        printf("<P>Error in invocation - wrong FORM probably.");
    else {
        fgets (input , sizeof(input) , stdin);

        char *loginS = malloc(sizeof(input));
        strcpy(loginS, input);

        user = strtok(loginS, delim[0]);
        user = strtok(user, delim[1]);
        user = strtok(NULL, delim[1]);

        pass = strtok(input, delim[0]);
        pass = strtok(NULL, delim[0]);
        pass = strtok(pass, delim[1]);
        pass = strtok(NULL, delim[1]);
        printf("%s@%s", user, pass);
        free(loginS);
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some bugs:

- `malloc()` can fail.  When it does, it returns a null pointer, which we must not use as destination for `strcpy()`.
- The fixed-length `input` array can be overrun by the remote user.  That's a pattern that causes security problems in server code (which this is, via CGI).  Our strategy to avoid that (by reading only `sizeof input - 1` chars) means that we silently change the user's input.

Other issues:

- Instead of reading into `input` and then copying into `loginS`, we should allocate memory, then (if successful) call `fgets(loginS, size, stdin)`.
- We should be testing for valid input *before* we output any headers, as we should be returning a HTTP error code (probably `400 Bad Request`) rather than success (`200`).
- We could parse `lenstr`, and if successful, use that value to allocate a suitable size buffer instead of `sizeof input` chars (which will always be `MAXINPUT`).  Don't forget `+ 1` for a terminating null char!
- I don't think the `delim` array is helpful - it would be clearer to put the literal strings in the code there.  I know that breaks the rule of "no magic values", but I think that here the rule just obfuscates rather than clarifies the code.
- If the `printf()` fails, it might be a good idea to return `EXIT_FAILURE`, so the CGI engine knows that something has gone wrong (the user hasn't got their result).
- Instead of `if`/`else`, I prefer an early-return pattern:

  ```
    if (error_condition) {
        report_error();
        cleanup_resources();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
  ```

  That means less context to hold in mind whilst reading.

Comment: Have posted an update here, If you want to have a look, thank you for these points. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276049/c-lang-cgi-form-update